# Creating Delegate of down-casted class to pass to function on Base class

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to create a delegate of a non-static method on my subclass, `ExchangeA`. I then want to pass this delegate method to another non-static method on the base-class `Exchange`. I say non-static because, firstly, they are, and secondly, the examples I have found online have mostly been with regard to static methods.

I have sought [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) as a resource.

```
public class Exchange {
    public int retrieve( string szLevel, string szJson, Func<string, string, Instrument> delegateMethod) {
        // ...
        Instrument instrument = delegateMethod(szLevel, szJson)
        // ...
        return someInt;
    }
}

public class ExchangeA : Exchange {
    public Instrument instrumentDataProcess( string szLevel, szJson ) {
        // ...
        return someInstrument;
    }
}

public class Instrument { ... }

public class DoStuff {
    public static Exchange ExchangeHandler( my args ) {
        Exchange oExchange = new ExchangeA(); // Could also be ExchangeB or ExchangeC being instantiated here

        Type type = oExchange.GetType(); // type == ExchangeA

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod( "instrumentDataProcess" );

        Func<string, string, Instrument> delegateFunc = (Func<string, string, Instrument>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, string, Instrument>), methodInfo); // fails here at runtime

        iRet = (int)type.InvokeMember( "retrieve", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oExchange, new object[] { szLevel, szCurrencyBase, delegateFunc });

        if (iRet == 0)
            return nil;
        return oExchange;
    }
}
```

It fails during execution when calling the `CreateDelegate()` method.

The error says:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot bind to the target method because its
>   signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the
>   delegate type.

Signature or security transparency? I already know the method signature because I defined it and I don't understand what security transparency means... I'm not usually a C# dev. All of my classes and functions are declared as public.

All comments and suggestions are valued! I want to learn the nonsense that is C#! ;)

**Update:**

Suggestions so far are to pass a method group as a parameter to my retrieve method. This is a new concept for me and I'm not sure how it's done. Does the parameter type `Func<string, string, Instrument>` still apply?

Comment: Why are you using `CreateDelegate` to create the delegate and not just assigning the method group?

Comment: Looks like you need to specify an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a delegate at all, you can just assign the method group:

```
public class Exchange {
    public int retrieve( string szLevel, string szJson, Func<string, string, Instrument> delegateMethod) {
        // ...
        Instrument instrument = delegateMethod(szLevel, szJson)
        // ...
        return someInt;
    }
}

public class ExchangeA : Exchange {
    public Instrument instrumentDataProcess( string szLevel, szJson ) {
        // ...
        return someInstrument;
    }
}

public class Instrument { ... }

public class DoStuff {
    public static Exchange ExchangeHandler( my args ) {
        Exchange oExchange = new ExchangeA(); // Could also be ExchangeB or ExchangeC being instantiated here

        iRet = oExchange.retrieve(szLevel, szCurrencyBase, oExchange.instrumentDataProcess);

        if (iRet == 0)
            return nil;
        return oExchange;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `iRet = oExchange.retrieve(szLevel, szCurrencyBase, oExchange.retrieve);`. And when I do this, it says `cannot convert from method group to Exchange.retrieve`... Also, do I not need to change the last parameter of the retrieve function?

Comment: Apologies for the typo and the late reply. You would pass in the method you were trying to convert to a `Func<string, string, Instrument>` in your sample, in this case `ExchangeA.instrumentDataProcess` I've edited my answer

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again but I'm still stuck. First, you have an inconsistency in your comment and your answer. Class name or or object instance dot method name? I have tried both and both provide me with errors. On the instance oExchange I get `Exchange does not contain a definition for 'instrumentDataProcess' and no extension method accepting accepting a first argument 'instrumentDataProcess' of type 'Exchange' could be found` and on the class, ExchangeA, `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property`. First parameter of method should be type of class?

Comment: Logically, I would agree with your answer: `oExchange.instrumentDataProcess` because it is an instance method that I'm calling. And the method isn't on the base class Exchange but only on every subclass of Exchange.

Comment: Well, since it always needs the same signature, you can add that method as an abstract method to your base class. Since all of the subclasses will need it anyway I don't see a problem.